# Native Facebook App Logout without access token

Tags: c#, facebook, logout

Using facebook C# SDK for a native app to be used in kiosk mode.

Scenario:

1. User logs in to facebook.
2. App request permission.
3. User deny permission.
4. Unable to programatically log user out of facebook since no access token has been granted.
   (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

What is the best approach in the above scenario where the next user of the app should start from scratch?

Comment: Why is there no access token, after you have done step 1?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't keep track of the user information until AFTER they Approve the permission. Just rework the flow of the program.

Comment: @CBroe After user logs in to facebook, the user still have to explicitly grant the app permission (in step 2), it is at this step the user can choose to deny permission. But the cookie has been created, so the next time OAuth dialog shows up for a new user, you will still land at "Step 2" under the previous user credentials.

Comment: To add on, I'm using a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control in a WPF app, running IE10. Using InternetSetOption() pinvoke method doesn't work when clearing browser session.